# Visual Studio 2015 support for automatic brace completion with ECMAScript 6

Tags: visual-studio, ecmascript-6

[image]

I tried to use `` (back ticks) like in the picture, but it looks like EcmaScript5 didn't support those.

So I changed the Javascript version to ECMAScript 6 like this:
[image]

But then, automatic brace completion didn't work. So whenever I type a `{` , I had to type `}` also. It's so annoying. 
[image]

I googled very hard to repair this problem, but couldn't fix it.

-----addition
[image]
I already checked TypeScript>General>Automatic brace completion. But it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the setting under `TypeScript -> General` and check whether the Auto-completion is enabled or not.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. ah.. this is a bug still going on refer the [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/1142)

Comment: Thank you for your kindness! I was anxious because I thought it's my fault.